# Connecting LAN's of OpenVPN clients and server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have recently set up an OpenVPN server running on Ubuntu 17. I am trying to let any client on the OpenVPN network access any other client's (and the server's) LAN's. Currently, if you connected to my server from another network, the VPN's network map (all devices accessible + route from client to server) would look like this:

```
 ________        _________        ___________        _________        ________
|        |      |         |      |           |      |         |      |        |
| Client | <--> | Gateway | <--> | INTERNET! | <--> | Gateway | <--> | Server |
|________|      |_________|      |___________|      |_________|      |________|
```

But, what I want it to look like is this:

```
 ________        _________        ___________        _________        ________
|        |      |         |      |           |      |         |      |        |
| Client | <--> | Gateway | <--> | INTERNET! | <--> | Gateway | <--> | Server |
|________|      |_________|      |___________|      |_________|      |________|
       _________     |    _________         _________    |    ___________
      | Device  |  <-|-> | Device  |       | Another | <-|-> | Device on |
      |   on    |    |   |   on    |       | Device  |   |   |    LAN    |
      |  LAN    |    |   |   LAN   |       |   on    |   |   |___________|
      |_________|    V   |_________|       |   LAN   |   |
                   Etc.                    |_________|    \--> Etc.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible, it's called a site-to-site VPN. There are enough guides on the internet on how to achieve this. If you have any more specific questions, please come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

## Yes

See OpenVPN's [Routed LANs](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans) page for practical examples of routing beyond the two OpenVPN nodes themselves.